# Is this Campden safe to use?

Tags: wine, alcohol, fermentation, mead

Campden was really hard to find in the country I am currently in. Thus a friend arranged it from a lab supplier.

As it shows 10ppm max lead on the label, would it be toxic to use?

Also could you suggest me an alternative to Campden to prevent bacteria? My wines and kimchi get flowering every second day of fermentation.

Would be very grateful for your guidance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: More appropriate for Homebrew SE.

Comment: IMO it would not be safe. But that is simply my point of view. It contains lead and that is not good! Over time it could possibly poison your system.

Comment: The lead specification is given as MAX, as in it is a guarantee that there is only minor trace elements. Given the dose to volume of drink, this would be negligible. @KenGraham, you should *not* look up lead content of fruit juices and others - food is your main source of lead most people do *not* die from lead poisoning.

Answer (score 1):

It will be safe to use and non-toxic. The maximum lead content is a maximum, and the one specified here is within safe limits. Breathing the air downwind from a coal-fired power station typically exposes you to more lead than this stuff, when used in the regular amounts.

One Campden tablet typically contains 0.44 g each of sodium metabisulphite (plus filler/binder, typically lactose). Potassium metabisulfite is slightly stronger than sodium metabisulfite by volume (17% stronger) but this is not enough to be taken into account if you are only making 5 or 10 gallons at a time.